# Where to meet "westernized" Thais in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, socializing

I moved to Bangkok about 5 months ago and started using Tinder for going on dates and potentially finding a partner. Initially it seemed great and I had high hopes, but after 7-8 dates or so I realized that even though a fairly large percentage of the Thai women on Tinder have a university education and in some cases have studied a semester or two abroad, they are still very "Thai" in their way of reasoning and lack good english communication skills.

After a few months of first-and-last-dates that were "okay" but just lacked something, I got bored and gave it up because I realized that I need to find someone who I can really communicate with and who  understands (for lack of a better expression) "western" thinking and reasoning. That probably means having lived abroad at least a few years, speaking and understanding english fluently and just being aware of (and at least somewhat interested in) what goes on outside the world of Facebook, online gossip and Thailand in general.

I know they exist out there, often you can overhear someone having an interesting conversation in perfect english with a Thai woman on the metro, in the mall or somewhere else. So I'm thinking there must be a better way of meeting those kinds of people than sifting through 100's of uninspiring Tinder profiles that are either blank, or make it obvious that the english skills are not that good.

Are there any particular places or events (online or IRL in Thailand) that I haven't thought about, where the odds of meeting "westernized" Thais are better than just any random place?

Comment: "Almost daily you can catch someone having an interesting conversation in perfect english with a Thai woman on the metro, in the mall or somewhere else" - maybe start talking to them when you see them?

Comment: Thanks, but if I was the kind of guy who does that, I most likely wouldn't be using Tinder and asking this question in the first place?

Comment: To me (I have lived in Thailand for some time) it made sense to learn Thai. If you are going to live in a country, why not learn some of the culture and communicate with the locals in their own language? Thai people are very happy when foreigners try to learn some Thai (possibly because it is a very difficult language to speak properly), and it can open a lot of doors.